# Android Animation stops working after being repeated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view, translate-animation

I have a slideshow of views in android, which has a slide in transition, the slideshow works perfectly for a while then the animation stops working, the views just appear without slide in.
Here is the an exampple of the code I am using, with a handler it's repeated each 10 seconds

`

```
TranslateAnimation slideIn = new TranslateAnimation(TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,1f,TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF ,0f,TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0f);
 slideIn.setDuration(250);
 slideIn.setFillAfter(true);
  container.startAnimation(slideIn);
```

`

container is a RelativeLayout that has the updated views, each 10 seconds i update the container views and call SlideIn animation

Any idea why the animation stops working?

Answer (score 1):

Remove handler and try after adding these lines -

```
    slideIn.setRepeatCount(10);
    slideIn.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
```

Comment: handler can't be removed as i need to change the content of the views